# Solving Heat Equation PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need some help on solving this heat PDE :

Question : Consider a bar length L. The face at x=0 is insulated so that the heat flow across is zero, and the face at x=L is held at temperature u=0. The temperature distribution is governed by heat equation

$$ {\partial u \over \partial t} - k {\partial ^2 u \over \partial x^2} =0$$

Show that the normal modes of u(x,t) are

$$\large U_n(x,t)=B_n\cos[(2n-1)\pi x/2L]e^{[-(2n-1)^2\pi^2k^2t]/4L^2}$$

Given BCs are : u(0,t)=0 and u(L,t)=0

I already solve this PDE

and I got my answer in this form :

$$\large U_n(x,t)=B_n\sin[n\pi x/2L] e^{[-(n)^2\pi^2k^2t]/4L^2}$$

How am I need to change my answer into the form they asking ??? Anyone willing to help me ?

Comment: Isn't the B.C. at x=0 expressed as $u_t (0,t) = 0$, as the temperature at $x=0$ isn't changing due to the insulation?

Comment: No it cant. Because boundary condition is given in interval 0<x<L. The one you said only applies for ICs only. But in this case ICs are not given

Comment: I'm pretty sure rlgordonna is correct: if the heat flow across x=0 is 0, that means $u_t (0,t) = 0$. This should lead to the right eigenfunction, too.

Comment: Ok let me try it out first and then I confirm back to you again

Comment: I cant get it. I think it mucg be easier if you could could show me the steps on how you done it Andrew Gibson. Please help me out

Comment: Here is a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190040/how-to-solve-partial-u-over-partial-t-k-partial-2-u-over-partial-x).

Comment: thanks Mhenni for the link

Comment: @Garett: You are welcome.

Comment: No need to put [solved] in the title. Accepting an answer signals that the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks Asaf for telling me that. Because i'm new to this forum so i tought i need to write solved. Thanks once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to express the problem as

$$u_t = k u_{xx} $$

$$ u_x(0,t) = 0 ,\;\;\; u(L,t) = 0 $$

Use separation of variables, i.e. $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ and get

$$X'' + \frac{\lambda}{k} X = 0 $$

where $-\lambda$ is the separation constant.  The solution to this equation is

$$ X(x) = A \cos{\left (\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}} x \right)} + B \sin{\left (\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}} x \right)}$$

The condition at $x=0$ implies that $B=0$:

$$ X'(x) = -\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}} A \sin{\left (\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}} x \right)} + B \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}}\cos{\left (\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}} x \right)}$$

$$X'(0) = B \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}} = 0$$

The condition at $x=L$ implies that

$$\cos{\left (\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}} L \right)} = 0$$

so that

$$\lambda = \left [ (2 n-1) \frac{\pi}{2 L} \right ]^2 k $$

You should be able to take it from there with the time equation.

Comment: I just cant get the part where you do X'(x). Shouldnt the BCs $u_t(0,t)=O$ which is $X(0)T'(t)=0$?? Why you did X'(x) rlgordonma? Could you explain

Comment: My mistake - it should be $u_x(0,t) = 0$.  I will fix it above.

Comment: For some reason, I mixed up holding a fixed temp., and heat flow, with is a temp. flux, i.e. a gradient, i.e., a spatial derivative.  I hope that clears it up.

Comment: Ok now I understand. But just one thing could you teach me how you indentify it is $u_x(0,t)=0$ rather than $u_t(0,t)=0$ or $u(0,t)=0$. Tell me some tips so that I can understand clearly about this part

Comment: My comment above should explain some of it.  The B.C.'s are described using certain terms.  If the temp is held fixed to zero at one end, then $u=0$ at that end.  If the temp is held fixed over time in general, then $u_t = 0$, which obviously returns a similar result to just setting $u=0$ at that end.  (My mistake in being so glib before and confusing you.)  If there is no heat flow, or the end is insulated, then $u_x = 0$ at that end.

Comment: BTW in two dimensions, if you are solving the heat eq'n with a zero flux B.C. at an edge of the region of interest, then you will have to apply what is called a Neumann B.C., which is the component of the gradient of the temp at that edge, normal to the edge.  The notation is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = \hat{\text{n}} \cdot \vec{\nabla} u = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so so much rlgordonma. Your expalanation is great  and now I can understand well. Once again thanks for helping me