# About a PDE problem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this PDE problem:

$u_t=\frac{1}{5}u_{xx}$

on $[-1,1]$ with periodic boundary conditions, and taking as initial data the function $u_0=1+\sin^2(\pi x)+\sin^2(2\pi x)$

I want to obtain the analytic solution. I think i can solve it separating variables and applying Fourier after that, ¿but anyone knows a shorter or easier way to get the solution?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190040/how-to-solve-partial-u-over-partial-t-k-partial-2-u-over-partial-x/190071#190071).

Comment: How is this question different from [the one you asked the other day](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190040/how-to-solve-partial-u-over-partial-t-k-partial-2-u-over-partial-x/190071#190071)? Also, it is not clear to me that you know what constitutes "periodic boundary conditions". It would be better if you explicitly state the PDE, BC(s), IC(s) you are considering.

Comment: Hi, John. I know how to solve it as I said, but I was asking for some "trick" method working in these cases, like the one 5PM has proposed, to avoid applying separation of variables and Fourier techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic thing to remember is that the function $u=Ce^{- \alpha \beta^2 t} \cos \beta x$ satisfies $u_t = \alpha u_{xx}$ (direct verification), for any $C$   and $\beta$. In your case $\alpha=1/5$.

Thus, whenever your initial data is given as a sum of trigonometric functions $C_k \cos \beta_k x$, you are in luck: just multiply each by exponential term $e^{- \alpha \beta_k^2 t} $  and you have the solution.

Your initial data is indeed of the above form, thanks to the identity $\sin^2y =\frac{1-\cos 2y}{2}$.