# Analytical solution to PDE (2)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Does the PDE $$u_{tt} = u_{xxx}$$ with $x \in [0,1]$ and $t \in [0,T]$ with initial conditions $$u(x,0)=\sin(\pi x),\, \partial_t u(x,0)=0$$ and boundary condition $$u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$$
have a analytical solution.

Comment: There needs to be another condition at the boundary e.g., $\partial_x (0,t) = 0$ to fully specify the solution uniquely.

Comment: Can you explain. Because I think it's enough for a numerical solution using finite difference.

Comment: 3rd degree in $x$.  When you do separation of variables, you'll get a 3rd degree ODE, which requires 3 conditions to uniquely specify.

Comment: Does this also apply when it can't be solved by separation of variables?

Comment: Yes, I think so, especially so if it is linear.

Comment: I tried to solve this equation with u(x,t)=X(x)T(t) but this didn't give me any solution that satisfied the initial conditions.

Comment: I don't see what you mean.

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on what you did.  Your solution should resemble a Fourier series of some sort.

Comment: It's not quite true that you always require the same number of boundary conditions as derivatives. That said, it's quite unlikely that 2 boundary conditions are enough in this case.

Comment: $u_{tt}=u_{xxx}, \quad$

$u(x,t)=X(x)T(t), \quad$

$u(x,0)=X(x)T(0)=\sin{\pi x}, \quad$

$X(x)=\frac{\sin{\pi x}}{T(0)}, \quad$

$u_{xxx}=X_{xxx}(x)T(t), \quad u_{tt}=X(x)T_{tt}(t), \quad$

$\frac{T_{tt}(t)}{T(t)} = \frac{X_{xxx}(x)}{X(x)} = \lambda^2 = - \pi^2\frac{\cos{\pi x}}{\sin{\pi x}}$

Comment: Since $\lambda^2$ is constant this can't be, right?

Comment: You're not doing separation of variables correctly. $\sin \pi x$ is not supposed to be assumed to be the result's form. You're meant to solve the separated ODEs independently in terms of $\lambda$ to construct separated solutions, and then combine separated solutions (with multiplication by an unknown constant) to form the general solution. Then find the constants necessary to satisfy the initial conditions.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it actually *might* be possible with the available boundary conditions.

Comment: But not with separation of variables right. Since $\lambda=0$ gives a polynomial solution, so it can't satisfy the initial conditions. And $X_{xxx}=\pm X(x)$ gives $ c_1e^{\pm x}+ c_2 e^{\mp x/2}  \cos{\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}}+c_3 e^{\mp x/2} \sin{\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}}$, which also can't satisfy the initial condition either.

Comment: Once again, you're not doing separation of variables correctly. I'm writing up a "solution" right now with the separation of variables approach, although unfortunately it's a little too unwieldy for me to solve with any sort of ease.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190040/how-to-solve-partial-u-over-partial-t-k-partial-2-u-over-partial-x) for the separation of variables..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using separation of variables, let

$$
\frac{T_{tt}}{T} = \frac{X_{xxx}}{X} = \lambda^6
$$
where we're assuming that $u=T(t)X(x)$. (Do you understand why I chose $\lambda^6$? Keep in mind that $\lambda$ need not be real) This allows us to find the general solutions

$$
T(t) = A_1e^{\lambda^3 t}+A_2e^{-\lambda^3 t}\\
X(x) = B_1e^{\lambda^2 x}+B_2e^{\alpha\lambda^2 x}+B_3e^{\alpha^2\lambda^2 x}
$$
where $\alpha^3 = 1$ is one of the roots other than $\alpha=1$. We'll use $\alpha = -\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Now, we'll find restrictions that satisfy our boundary conditions. We have
$$
X(0)=B_1+B_2+B_3 = 0\\
X(1)=B_1e^{\lambda^2}+B_2e^{\alpha \lambda^2}+B_3e^{\alpha^2\lambda^2}=0\\
-(B_2+B_3)e^{\lambda^2}+B_2e^{\alpha \lambda^2}+B_3e^{\alpha^2 \lambda^2}=0\\
B_2(e^{\alpha \lambda^2}-e^{\lambda^2})+B_3(e^{\alpha^2 \lambda^2}-e^{\lambda^2})=0
$$
So let's write that

$$
X(x) = \hat C\left(\frac{e^{\alpha \lambda^2 x}-e^{\lambda^2 x}}{(e^{\alpha \lambda^2}-e^{\lambda^2})}-\frac{e^{\alpha^2 \lambda^2 x}-e^{\lambda^2 x}}{(e^{\alpha^2 \lambda^2}-e^{\lambda^2})}\right)
$$

We also know that

$$
T'(0) = A_1\lambda^3-A_2\lambda^3 = 0
$$
So $A_1=A_2$ (except when $\lambda=0$), or $T(t) = \hat A \cosh \lambda^3 t$.

So now we have that

$$
u(x,t)=\int C(\lambda)\cosh (\lambda^3 t)\left(\frac{e^{\alpha \lambda^2 x}-e^{\lambda^2 x}}{(e^{\alpha \lambda^2}-e^{\lambda^2})}-\frac{e^{\alpha^2 \lambda^2 x}-e^{\lambda^2 x}}{(e^{\alpha^2 \lambda^2}-e^{\lambda^2})}\right)d\lambda
$$

Now, $u(x,0)=\sin \pi x$, so

$$
\int C(\lambda)\left(\frac{e^{\alpha \lambda^2 x}-e^{\lambda^2 x}}{(e^{\alpha \lambda^2}-e^{\lambda^2})}-\frac{e^{\alpha^2 \lambda^2 x}-e^{\lambda^2 x}}{(e^{\alpha^2 \lambda^2}-e^{\lambda^2})}\right)d\lambda = \sin \pi x
$$
This is how one does separation of variables.

Let's suppose that our solution will remain bounded - this requires that $\lambda^3$ is imaginary, and so $\lambda$ is also imaginary. So we have $\lambda=ik$. In this case, $\lambda^2=-k^2$, and our separable components look like

$$
T(t) = \hat A \cos (k^3 t)
$$
and
$$
X(x) = \hat C\left(\frac{e^{-\alpha k^2 x}-e^{-k^2 x}}{e^{-\alpha k^2}-e^{-k^2}}-\frac{e^{-\alpha^2 k^2 x}-e^{-k^2 x}}{e^{-\alpha^2 k^2}-e^{-k^2}}\right)
$$
We could simplify this by converting $e^{-\alpha k^2 x}$ to $e^{k^2x/2}(\cos(\sqrt{3}k^2x/2)+i\sin(\sqrt{3}k^2x/2))$ and $e^{-\alpha^2 k^2 x}$ to $e^{k^2x/2}(\cos(\sqrt{3}k^2x/2)-i\sin(\sqrt{3}k^2x/2))$.

The problem, however, is that we cannot reasonably restrict the possible values of $k$ (for a finite domain, it is often restricted to a discrete set of numbers, allowing a sum formula), beyond noting that $k\geq 0$ is sufficient. Our integral defining $C(k)$ is

$$
\int_0^\infty C(k) \left(\frac{e^{-\alpha k^2 x}-e^{-k^2 x}}{e^{-\alpha k^2}-e^{-k^2}}-\frac{e^{-\alpha^2 k^2 x}-e^{-k^2 x}}{e^{-\alpha^2 k^2}-e^{-k^2}}\right)dk = \sin(\pi x)
$$