# Fourier series method

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following Boundary value problem 
 
$U_t-U_{xx}=0$ from  zero to one; $t>0$ 
$ U(x,0)=x$ from zero to one 
 
$U(0,t)=U(1,t)=0$ 
 
I need to solve it using the Fourier series method, But I don't know for which $f(x)$ I need to find the solution. Is $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=x$?

Comment: Use separation of variables techniques. If you search the website you can find many answers to the question.

Comment: @science but What about the fourier series?

Comment: @science I need to solve first the problem using separation of variables and then Find the fourier series?

Comment: In between you need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SolvingHeatEquation.aspx).

Comment: @science thats why I'm so confuse, because he explain a problem, but it never involve eigen values or eigen vectors. he gave to us the fourier series formulas and thats it. And online I see all this crazy things that I don't understand really well.

Comment: See the link I gave you.

Comment: @science I can't see the link. Can you post it again?

Comment: See [I](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SolvingHeatEquation.aspx), [II](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511143/heat-equation-identity-with-dirichlet-boundary-condition).

Comment: @science Thank you very much!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pde $u_{t} = u_{xx}$ with the conditions $u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0$, $u(x,0) = x$ the following is the solution. 
Let $u(x,t) = F(x) G(t)$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{G'}{G} = - \lambda^{2} = \frac{F''}{F}
\end{align}
and leads to the two equations $G' + \lambda^{2} G = 0$ and $F'' + \lambda^{2} F = 0$. The solutions are 
\begin{align}
G(t) &= e^{- \lambda^{2} t} \\
F(x) &= A \cos(\lambda x) + B \sin(\lambda x).
\end{align}
For the conditions $u(0,t), u(1,t)$ leads to $F(0) = 0, F(1) = 0$ and the solution $F(x) = B \sin(n \pi x)$ for which the general solution becomes
\begin{align}
u(x,t) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n} \, e^{- n^{2} \pi^{2} t} \, \sin(n \pi x).
\end{align}
The coefficients are found by use of the Fourier sine series are are seen, in this case, by
\begin{align}
B_{n} &= 2 \int_{0}^{1} x \, sin(n \pi x) \, dx \\
&= \frac{2}{n \pi} \left( 1 - (-1)^{n} \right).
\end{align}
This leads to the general solution
\begin{align}
u(x,t) &= \frac{2}{\pi} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 - (-1)^{n}}{n} \, e^{- n^{2} \pi^{2} t} \, \sin(n \pi x) \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n+1} \, e^{-(2n+1)^{2} \pi^{2} t} \, \sin((2n+1) \pi x)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the solution. My solution is a little different, because I have sin(pi*x*n). I want to post it, but I don't know how to write it over here. @Leucippus

Comment: @Evangelina There is a button at the bottom of the page that says "Answer your question". If you click on it the standard "enter your data area" is then available.