# Boundary Value Problem (Separation of Variables)

Tags: fourier-series, self-learning, solution-verification, boundary-value-problem

> Solve the boundary value problem
>   \begin{cases}
> u_{t}-2u_{xx}=0 \\ u_{x}(0,t)=u_{x}(\pi,t)=0, \quad x\in[0,\pi], t\geq0 \\ u(x,0)=\cos^{2}(x)
> \end{cases}

**My Attempt**

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$. Then

\begin{equation}
u_{t}-2u_{xx}=0 \iff X(x)T'(t)-2X''(x)T(t)=0
\end{equation}
which implies
\begin{equation}
\frac{T'(t)}{2T(t)}=\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\lambda^{2}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
X''(x)+\lambda^{2}X(x)=0 
\end{equation}
where the general solution is given as
\begin{equation}
X_{n}(x)=A\cos(\lambda_{n}x)+B\sin(\lambda_{n}x)
\end{equation}
The boundary conditions $X_{x}(0)=X(\pi)=0$, with
\begin{equation} X'(x)=-A\lambda_{n}\sin(\lambda_{n}x)+B\lambda_{n}\cos(\lambda_{n} x) \end{equation}
gives

\begin{equation} X_{x}(0)=0 \implies B\lambda_{n}=0 \implies B=0 \end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation} X_{x}(\pi)=0 \implies -A\lambda_{n}\sin(\lambda_{n}\pi)=0 \implies \lambda_{n}=n \end{equation}
So, we have 
\begin{equation} T'(t)+2n^{2}T(t)=0 \end{equation}
which has the solution
\begin{equation}
T_{n}(t)=e^{-2n^{2}t}
\end{equation}

By superposition, we have
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\cos(nx)e^{-2n^{2}t}
\end{equation}
where the constant term $A_{n}$ is determined by the initial condition $u(x,0)=\cos^{2}(x)$. Here I am lead to believe $T_{1}(0)=\cos(x)$ and $T_{n}(0)=0$ for $n \not =1$. So  \begin{equation}u(x,t)=\cos^{2}(x)e^{-2t} \end{equation} **But, when I check this result it becomes clear that it is wrong. Where does my argument slip into chaos?**

Comment: But, $T$ is a function of $T$. How can you have it depending on $x$? You need to calculate Fourier coefficients.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190040/how-to-solve-partial-u-over-partial-t-k-partial-2-u-over-partial-x).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)$. This is the Fourier series for $\cos^2(x)$.