# Question about separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

This is for the heat equation, where

$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}-k \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2}=1$$ with the conditions $$U(0,t)=0, \; U(x,0)=0 \text{ and } \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} (3,t)=0.$$

I am trying to solve for $U(x,t)$ but am currently stuck with factoring dealing with the "$+1$" in the separation of variables.

I started with $U(x,t)=F(x) G(t)$ then put it into the heat equation and set it equal to a constant -$\lambda^2$.  To deal with the $+1$, I moved it to the other side with the lambda but now I am can't seem to get the sine or exponential expression I need.

Comment: Can you solve the equation for the new function $v = u - t$?

Comment: how does this fit into the scheme of things here?

Comment: Have you been asked to use the separation of variables techniques?

Comment: @mvgwpemb what do you mean? What I've suggested is pretty much the same as Alex posted.

Answer (score 3):

Let $V=U-t$. Then

$$V_t-kV_{xx}=0.$$

Now do separation of variables (work out the appropriate boundary conditions for $V$ as well).

Comment: Actually, your hint leads nowhere since for the new variable you get time dependent boundary conditions.

Comment: @Artem: why is that bad?

Comment: Because separation of variables works if and only if the boundary conditions are homogeneous (zero)

Comment: @Artem: one can generalize separation of variables for time dependent boundaries. See for example this:         http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0017931062900637         (Sorry for the paywall)

Comment: This is a very nice confirmation of my original statement: Your hint leads nowhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First assume the solution has the form

> $$ u ( x,t ) = F_1 ( x ) F_2( t)+c_1+c_2x-\frac{1}{2k}\,x^2, $$

then advance with [separation of variables technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190040/how-to-solve-partial-u-over-partial-t-k-partial-2-u-over-partial-x).