# How do we get get from $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} v_t= \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} v_{xx}+s''(x)$ to $s''(x)=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

To solve the problem:
$$(1):u_t=u_{xx}, 0<x<L, t>0$$
$$u(0,t)=T_1, u(L,t)=T_2, t>0$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x), 0<x<L$$
we do the following:
$$(2):u(x,t)=v(x,t)+s(x)$$
where $s(x)$ is a stationary of the initial boundary value problem $(1)$ while $t$ goes to infinity, that means that $s(x)=\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} u(x,t), 0<x<L$

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} u(x,t)= \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} v(x,t)+ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} s(x) \Rightarrow \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} v(x,t)=0, 0<x<L$$

Replacing the relation $(2)$ into the relation $(1)$, we get:
$$(5):v_t=v_{xx}+s''(x), 0<x<L, t>0$$
$$v(x,0)+(x)=f(x), 0<x<L$$
$$v(0,t)+s(0)=T_1$$
$$v(L,t)+S(L)=T_2$$

Taking the limit $t \rightarrow \infty$ at the relations $(5)$, we have:
$$s''=0, 0<x<L$$
$$s(0)=T_1$$
$$s(L)=T_2$$

---

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} v_t= \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} v_{xx}+s''(x)$$
$$v(x,0)+s(x)=f(x) \Rightarrow v(x,t)=f(x)-s(x)$$
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}v(0,t)+s(0)=T_1 \Rightarrow 0+s(0)=T_1$$
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} v(L,t)+s(L)=T_2 \Rightarrow 0+s(L)=T_2$$

But how do we get get from 
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} v_t= \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} v_{xx}+s''(x), 0<x<L$$
to $$s''(x)=0, 0<x<L$$???

Comment: See a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190040/how-to-solve-partial-u-over-partial-t-k-partial-2-u-over-partial-x).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal My problem has non-homogeneous boundary conditions... The problem you sent me has homogeneous conditions, hasn't it??

Comment: You are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} v = 0$, it follows that $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} v_t = 0$ and also that $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} v_{xx} = 0$.

Edit: This follows because for instance:
$$\lim_{t\to \infty} v_t = \lim_{t\to \infty} \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{v(x,t+h) -v(x,t)}{h} 
= \lim_{h\to 0} \lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{v(x,t+h) -v(x,t)}{h}
= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{0-0}{h} = 0$$

Comment: Can we just derive the relation $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} v=0$$ and so we get the two limits are also equal to $0$?

Comment: @MaryStar: Yes. I have edited my answer to show this.

Comment: I got it!! Thanks for your answer!! :-)